# storing allowed settings combinations

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am making an interface where a user can define settings. The settings are separated in categories and the user can only select one parameter from each category. The thing is, only certain combinations of parameters are allowed and I must prevent the users from selecting incompatible parameters.

I am trying to design the mysql database structure for that but I did not find a solution that satisfies me.

What I thought of is :

```
Categories 
 - ID
 - Description

Parameters
 - ID
 - Parent Category ID
 - Description

Combinations
 -ID
 - a string that is the concatenation of parameters IDs ordered by category
```

eg. : 102596 would be the combination of parameters 10 from category 1, 25 from category 2, and 96 from category 3.

The problems is : what if one day I need more than a hundred parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok So you have these tables:

```
Categories 
 - ID
 - Description
```

And each category has multiple parameters:

```
Parameters
 - ID
 - Parent Category ID
 - Description
```

Now you want to store the parameters that the user has selected. Why dont you handle the operation of permitting of selecting only one parameter per category outside of the database design scope? If you can do that, then the combination table would be simple:

```
Combinations
 - ID
 - USER_ID
 - CATEGORY_ID
 - PAREMETER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a table for grouping combinations, as such:

```
Combinations
- ID
- Group_ID
- Parameter_ID
```

So for instance, let's use your example of the allowed combination 10, 25 and 96, you would have this 3 entries in the "Combinations" table:

```
(ID, Group_ID, Parameter_ID) = (1, 1, 10), (2, 1, 25), (3, 1, 96)
```

(the IDs can be auto-generated ones)

So that means you have this group (1) of 3 allowed parameters (10, 25, 96).

then if you want to add another possible combination of, say, 15, 16, 23 and 42:

```
(ID, Group_ID, Parameter_ID) = (4, 2, 15), (5, 2, 16), (6, 2, 23), (7, 2, 42)
```

(again the IDs can be auto-generated ones)

So that means you have this group (2) of 4 allowed parameters (15, 16, 23, 42).

Comment: This looks like a good solution but I can't figure out how to easily request groups that match certain parameters. If the user chose parameters 15 and 16, how do I know that group 2 and maybe other groups match these parameters so I can display only the remaining allowed parameters for him to choose from ? (eg. parameters 23 and 42 but not 41 or 56). The only way I can think of is to select all the groups that contain parameter 15, and then from that group set select all the groups that contain parameter 16 and so on. If there are many categories that makes many requests.